# Howto Emacs nyan-mode image in console

Tags: bash, terminal, emacs, images

I have emacs’ [nyan-mode](https://github.com/TeMPOraL/nyan-mode) working in my OS X desktop emacs (24.5). But I’d very much like to get that working in my console emacs. I’m using:

- Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS (precise), ***in a Vagrant VM***.
- (OSX) Terminal 2.5.3

Given that I'm in a Vagrant VM, I'm not sure this is possible. But would like to try. *Incidentally, the nyan image doesn't display in a non-vagrant console emacs, either*.

For the vagrant version, I’ve downloaded and compiled emacs 24.5 with [image support](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Images.html). And nyan-mode's actual image file is [an xpm](https://github.com/TeMPOraL/nyan-mode/tree/master/img), which emacs supports.

I’ve added my user to the "*video*" group, which owns the [frame buffer device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer)
( `....------ 1 root video 29, 0 Nov  9 04:09 /dev/fb0` ).

And still no dice. I've tried troubleshooting this, by trying out the [fbi console viewer](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/), as per this [SO post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-do-i-display-images-without-starting-x11). It runs without error, but no image displays. So I'm pretty sure the console just isn't setup to display images.

Is there anything I can do to display images in my console?

```
$ sudo fbi -T 1 <parent-dirs>/img/nyan.xpm 

using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

Comment: You could also try to use on the client side [MLTerm](https://bitbucket.org/arakiken/mlterm), which supports the Sixel format, a standard for sending pixels via escape sequences, or [terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology), which can show images too. You would just have to print the raw escape codes from your emacs configuration, and they would show up on the client side.